# Filtering process results removes desired output

Tags: powershell, memory

I'm tasked with connecting to some remote servers and retrieve information on the processes running on the server. There is no guarantee that each process will be running on the server.

Here is my code to retrieve the process information:

```
$processResult = (get-process trustedInstaller, werfault, econagt -computername $server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select name, @{l= "Private Memory (MB)"; e={$_.privatememorysize / 1mb}})
```

I then need to determine if any of the above process are consuming more the 10mb of memory. I've done so using this query:

```
$highProcess = $processResult | ? {$_.'Private Memory (GB)' -gt 1mb}
```

The above line of code is yielding no results, even though there are some process over the 10MB threshold.

Here is a sample output for `$processResult`:

```
DMOBBQ-008:@{Name=TrustedInstaller; Private Memory (MB)=2.36328125}
DCOBF1-003:@{Name=TrustedInstaller; Private Memory (MB)=12.546875}
DCOBF1-013:@{Name=TrustedInstaller; Private Memory (MB)=11.328125}
DCOBF2-005:@{Name=TrustedInstaller; Private Memory (MB)=11.00390625}
DCOBF2-006:@{Name=TrustedInstaller; Private Memory (MB)=12.2265625}
DCOBF2-007:@{Name=TrustedInstaller; Private Memory (MB)=11.55078125}
DCOBF2-015:@{Name=TrustedInstaller; Private Memory (MB)=13.40234375}
DMOBB8-007:@{Name=TrustedInstaller; Private Memory (MB)=11.99609375}
DMOBBE-000:@{Name=TrustedInstaller; Private Memory (MB)=11.22265625}
DMOBBQ-005:@{Name=TrustedInstaller; Private Memory (MB)=12.2890625}
DMOBBQ-006:@{Name=TrustedInstaller; Private Memory (MB)=2.40234375}
DMOBBQ-007:@{Name=TrustedInstaller; Private Memory (MB)=2.3671875}
DMOBBR-007:@{Name=TrustedInstaller; Private Memory (MB)=2.3671875}
DMOBC4-002:@{Name=TrustedInstaller; Private Memory (MB)=11.77734375}
DMOBBR-005:@{Name=TrustedInstaller; Private Memory (MB)=2.41015625}
DCOBBN-D06:@{Name=TrustedInstaller; Private Memory (MB)=12.0625}
```

Any input on why the results for `$highProcess` are null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your processresult unit is already MB. 1mb is converted to equivalent value in bytes, so you're comparing (for instance) 2.36328125 to a value of 1048576!

Comment: i changed the query to: `$highProcess = $processResult | ? {$_.'Private Memory (GB)' -gt 10}`

still no results

Comment: Change `Private Memory (GB)` to `Private Memory (MB)`. You should probably go with a better variable name anyways, though.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!
I'll definitely change the var name, I copied and pasted from another query!
I"ll accept your answer when available